# getting previous p tag with jquery to change background

Tags: jquery, background, mouseover, html-lists

i have the following problem. I have a css dropdown navigation and if there is a mouseover on the dropdown part of the navigation I want the background of the "navigation heading" to keep its background color that it gets when there is a hover on it. Problem is if the user moves on and hovers over the dropdown, the hover state of the "navigation heading" goes back to "normal". That's why I thought I could use jquery to alter it.

But unfortunately I don't know how to select the specific element.

Here is an example for the navigation:

```
<ul> 
                    <li> 
                        <p class="naviHead first">Finanzen</p> 
                            <ul> 
                                <li><a href="http://www.spardaxx.de/kredit" title="SparDaxx Ratenkredit">Ratenkredit</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.spardaxx.de/baufinanzierung" title="SparDaxx Baufinanzierung">Baufinanzierung</a></li>
                                <li><a href="http://www.spardaxx.de/altersvorsorge" title="SparDaxx Riester Rente">Riester Rente</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                    </li> 
                </ul>
```

So if the user hovers over the p tag, the dropdown ul opens. Now I want to change the background color of the p if someone hovers over the following ul..

here is my jquery so far

```
$().ready(function() {
            $('#TopNav ul ul').mouseover(function() {
                 $(this).parents('p.naviHead').filter(':first').css("background", "black");


            })
        });
```

I guess the solution i simple, but I have no idea.. So any help is appreciated. Thx! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).prev().css("backgroundColor", "black");
```

or if you have a more complex layout then -

```
$(this).parent().find('p.naviHead').css("backgroundColor", "black");
```

may be better

Comment: Thx! And do you have any idea how I can achieve that if the user leaves the ul again, the css of the parent p can be set back to the "default css values" it had before?

Comment: Brilliant, glad you are all sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).siblings('p.naviHead').css("background", "black");

$('#TopNav ul ul').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('p.naviHead').css("backgroundColor", "yourPreviosColor");
})
```

Comment: No, that was not exactly what I was looking for since I also had a background Image that had to come back.. But you didn't know that. I found a working solution myself.. .mouseout(function() {
      $(this).prev().css("background", "");

    
    }) But thank you very much!!! :)